# Generalized gamma random data generation

Tags: r, matlab, random

How to generate random data (synthetic data) from a generalized gamma distribution with three parameters (scale, shape and shape)?. Using Matlab or R. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `VGAM::gengamma` function.
See http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/vgam/docs/gengamma

Or `flexsurv::GenGamma`
see http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/flexsurv/html/GenGamma.html